# Getting error 404 while using Alteryx Gallery default URL

Tags: alteryx

I have installed Alteryx server in my Windows based 2008 R2 server But I am not able to use default Gallery Url http://localhost/gallery/

getting error code-404

Comment: Can you try try replacing "localhost" with the server''s IP?

Comment: Hey John, Thanks for the suggestion Actually Alteryx Services were not started at that time. We need to start it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The server may not be started, it starts manually after the initial install at times; check in `services.msc` to see if the Alteryx Service is running.